# Why is my local JPA setup not honored if using an EntityManagerFactory from JNDI using Spring?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, wildfly-8

`AuditingEntityListener` correctly updates columns marked with `@LastModifiedDate`, `@CreatedDate`, `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` in `dev` mode (`mvn jetty:run`) when I use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. However, when I activate `prod` profile and deploy in Wildfly 8, the columns are not updated.

I found on [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/96097-can-t-get-auditingentitylistener-to-fire): "You will need to use one of Spring's EntityManagerFactoryBeans to setup the EntityManagerFactory" Is there any way to use `AuditingEntityListener` with `<jee:jndi-lookup />` `EntityManagerFactory`?

Here is my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/local-container-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/postgresql-datasource" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/entity-manager-factory" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
</beans>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.corp.repository" factory-class="com.corp.RespositoryFactoryBean" />
<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="entityAuditorAware" />
<bean name="entityAuditorAware" class="com.corp.EntityAuditorAware" />
```

`orm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener class="org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener" />
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Make sure the `EntityManagerFactory` you obtain from JNDI is configured to have the `AuditingEntityListener` applied to the persistence unit you obtain.

### Details

In your `dev` profile, The `EntityManagerFactory` is created within your application and thus - by definition in the spec - considers the locally available `orm.xml`.

In you `prod` example you don't bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory` locally but obtain a preconfigured one from your application server. Thus you have to make sure the `EntityManagerFactory` instance is configured as you expected in the application server in the first place.

Comment: Oliver, thank you for your time. `AuditingEntityListener` gets initialized but `handler` is null in `touchForCreate` and `touchForUpdate` methods, so the columns are not updated. Debugging `AuditingBeanFactoryPostProcessor` I see `BeanDefinitionUtils.getEntityManagerFactoryBeanNames` returns an empty `Set` since `BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors` returns and empty `Set` for both `EntityManagerFactory.class` and `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.class`